# Static property lifetime or cache method inside dll

Tags: c#, database, caching

I need to know how caching a value for a short time inside a dll.
I have a n-tier application and one of my layer calls a method several times who calls the database, so i want to cache the result because it's the same each time (but it can be different if executed at another time)

Currently, my possibilities are:
- using a static variable but the result will never change until AppDomain expires
- keep it like that but i have some performance issues

Comment: As you pointed out, the lifetime of a static field is the AppDomain .. Anyway, there are different caching techniques - preferably left up to the database framework, where applicable. It might be appropriate to use a higher-than-database or even cross-cutting caching .. depending.

Comment: How do you access the database? Winows or web?

Comment: It's a web application ans i use the ORM Dapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of a static variable is the AppDomain lifetime.

If you use .NET4 or more, you can use the `MemoryCache`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx)